# PHP array field with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using an array to add data to my database, and JavaScript to show and hide field depending on yes and no.

```
<input type="radio" id="medication1" name="medication[]" value="Yes" />
<input type="radio" id="medication2" name="medication[]" value="No" />


 $("#show").hide();
        $("input[name=medication]").click(function()
        {
            if ($("#medication1").attr('checked'))
                $("#show2").hide();
            if ($("#medication2").attr('checked'))
                $("#show2").show();
        });
```

Without the array block quotes it works perfectly but once I add them it doesn't. Is there maybe a way I can get around this?

Comment: If it works without the [], why don't you just use it that way (I mean, in the form too!)? As this is a radio button, it won't ever have more than one selected... (also, what would be the semantics associated with having medication = ['Yes', 'No']?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
$("input[name=medication]").click(function()
```

to

```
$("input[name='medication[]']").click(function()
```

Answer (score 3):

You need escape those special meanings chars: `[]`:

```
$("input[name=medication\\[\\]]").click(function()
```

[**Source**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: using $('input[name="medication[]"]')

Comment: @rab, that's a valid way as well.

Answer (score 1):

try this with `^=` in your selector you tell to select all input with name that start with medication

```
$("#show").hide();
        $("input[name^=medication]").click(function()
        {
            if ($("#medication1").attr('checked'))
                $("#show2").hide();
            if ($("#medication2").attr('checked'))
                $("#show2").show();
        });
```